# Easy way to implement StackedInlines on views like Admin - Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

is there any package like Admin StackedInline to implement on frontend

i've used django-formsets but little complex !

**Eg : For Question and Answers App ( create-read-update-delete )**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) instead of regular formsets. It should be a lot easier.